# How to split a string enclosed with "{}" and "[]" using regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help me the Regular expression for the string like this

```
string input = {TEXT}_&[2].&[1].&[3];
input = {TEXT}_&[2].&[1];
```

I wanted to split the string as

```
TEXT
2
1
3

TEXT
2
1
```

I have got a regular expression which is splitting the square bracket content but i need a regex to match curly braces also

```
string pattern = @"\{([^]]*)\}";  //to get only curly brace content
string pattern = @"\[([^]]*)\]";  //to split square bracket content.
```

I need single pattern to split both

Comment: [`string pattern = @"\{([^]]*)\}|\[(\d+)\]";`](https://regex101.com/r/xG1iT0/1)

Comment: Would you like to just *match*? See [this demo](http://ideone.com/nTxp0N).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks, this is my exact answer. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the tokens with `Regex.Matches`:

```
var input = "{TEXT}_&[2].&[1].&[3]";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"{(?<p>[^}]*)}|\[(?<p>[^]]*)]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(p => p.Groups["p"].Value)
        .ToList();
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nTxp0N)

The pattern matches 2 alternatives:

*Alternative 1:*

- `{` - opening brace
- `(?<p>[^}]*)`  - 0+ characters other than a closing brace (Group "p")
- `}` - closing brace

*Alternative 2*:

- `[` - opening bracket
- `(?<p>[^]]*)` - 0+ characters other than a closing bracket (Group "p")
- `]` - closing bracket

The use of identically named capture groups is possible in .NET regex, that is why this approach works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split on

```
(?:\W|_)+
```

And remove the empty entries.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gN3pQ9/1